# Mice package for imputation - chains not intermingling

Tags: r, convergence, multiple-imputation, mice

I'm running an imputation using the `mice` package in R (imputing 7 variables with missing values on the basis of 10 total variables). The imputation runs fine, and the imputed variables look reasonable in terms of the spread and gaps compared to the original distributions.

Looking at the plot of the various imputation chains, not all of them are intermingling (see example for three variables below, the upper two are not intermingling, the third is), although none of them are showing any sort of trend (which is the only guidance I can find about what I should be looking for). Which variable this is happening for doesn't seem to be related to extent of missingness, or the extent of linear relatedness to any of the other variables, or anything else I can think of.

1. How worried do I need to be about this?
2. Is there anything I can actually do to mitigate this in any way?

[image: Imputation chains mean and SD]